# Cannot toggle markers Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, toggle, hide, show, marker

hey i have a problem to toggle my markers on/off

Do you have any idea why it toggles only one marker (marker "Freilichtmuseum") ?

thX for Help !!

```js
var locations = [
    ['Sensenwerk', 47.20031715397146, 15.338023278873152, 4],
    ['Freilichtmuseum', 47.158075170093, 15.315393984492403, 5],
];


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    function toggleLayer() {     
        if (marker.getMap() === null) {
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
        else {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the togglelayer function?

Comment: function toggleLayer(i)

Comment: hmm i dont know why it only toggles the last of the 2 markers :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

toggleLayer only toggles the current "marker".  If you want it to do more than the last one, you need to save references to all the markers that need to be toggled in an array and iterate through that array.

```
var markers = [];
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

    function toggleLayer() {     
      for (var i=0; i< markers.length; i++){
        if (markers[i].getMap() === null) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
        else {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
      }
    }
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9pk1ht9/)

Comment: ahh oke thank you m8. But i am very new in JavaScript so i dont know how tha do that ? may ya give me an example for the code, that would be very nice !

Comment: Perhaps you should refresh the question.  There is code and a working fiddle in my answer now.

Comment: You can [accept the answer to the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (you are the only one that can).

Comment: and how its possible to toggle only the "schools" the "museums" and "hotels" in my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/z9pk1ht9/2/ It would be very nice of you if you may explain it to me